# Testing backbone-relational with jasmine

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine, backbone-relational

**UPDATED:**

I have a simple Backbone-relational model:

```
@App.M.Product = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend
    defaults: {}
    url: App.D.dataURL
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasMany
            key: 'templates'
            relatedModel: 'App.M.Template'
            collectionType: 'App.C.Templates'
            reverseRelation:
                key: 'product'
        }
        {
            type: Backbone.HasMany
            key: 'pages'
            relatedModel: 'App.M.Page'
            collectionType: 'App.C.Pages'
            reverseRelation:
                key: 'product'
        }
        {
            type: Backbone.HasMany
            key: 'uploaded_images'
            relatedModel: 'App.M.UploadedImage'
            collectionType: 'App.C.UploadedImages'
            reverseRelation:
                key: 'product'
        }
    ]
    initialize: ->
        if @get('minimumNumberOfPages') < 1
            @set 'minimumNumberOfPages', 1
    fixPages: ->
        col = @get 'pages'
        col.each (page) ->
            page.collection = col
```

and an even simplier test suite:

```
"use strict"

describe 'Product', ->
    pr = null
    beforeEach ->
        pr = new App.M.Product
    it 'should be defined', ->
        expect(pr).toBeDefined()
```

However, the model fails to initialize (taken from testem's terminal output):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Backbone.HasMany.Backbone.Relation.extend.initialize (http://localhost:7357/app/bower_components/backbone-relational/backbone-relational.js:835:78)
    at Backbone.Relation (http://localhost:7357/app/bower_components/backbone-relational/backbone-relational.js:537:9)
    at new child (http://localhost:7357/app/bower_components/backbone/backbone-min.js:1:25220)
    at _.extend.initializeRelation (http://localhost:7357/app/bower_components/backbone-relational/backbone-relational.js:137:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:7357/app/bower_components/backbone-relational/backbone-relational.js:1176:31)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.w.each.w.forEach (http://localhost:7357/app/bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js:1:599)
    at Backbone.RelationalModel.Backbone.Model.extend.initializeRelations (http://localhost:7357/app/bower_components/backbone-relational/backbone-relational.js:1175:6)
    at Backbone.RelationalModel.Backbone.Model.extend.set (http://localhost:7357/app/bower_components/backbone-relational/backbone-relational.js:1373:11)
    at Backbone.Model (http://localhost:7357/app/bower_components/backbone/backbone-min.js:1:3929)
```

Why is that? The app is wokring correctly, the tests are not.

Answer (score 1):

So the error is `ReferenceError: product is not defined`. This cause you defined it in the `before` function **and** in the test, so both are not the same and in the test its undefined. You have to define it in your describe block :

"use strict"

describe 'Product', ->
    product = null

```
beforeEach ->
    product = new App.M.Product

it 'should be defined', ->
    expect(product).toBeDefined()
```

For the other error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`, it seems you have missed to add the collections mention under `collectionType`. So the plugin is looking for `App.C.Pages` in the global namespace and and try to get the prototype of the object. But as the error says its not defined

Comment: Thanks, that helps with the first part. How about the rest? http://pastebin.com/HUkNG9kC